# Unable to edit config.inc.php in the phpmyadmin configuration

Tags: terminal, permission, php

I'm trying to edit a file on my mac. The file is `config.inc.php` of XAMPP located in `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin`.

**Permission of the folder and file:**

Phpmyadmin -> `drwxr-xr-x 12 root wheel 4096`

Config.inc.php -> `-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 5109 config.inc.php`

I tried to open file with: `sudo nano config.inc.php` but it doesn't change it because it says i don't have permission to do it.

To changing the privileges with: `sudo chmod 777 config.inc.php`, but it doesn't make me modify it.

To reset privileges of the computer and create a new administrator User, but he doesn't want to know about changing the permissions.

I'm freaking out can anyone help me out?

Here a screenshot of the Terminal error:

[image: Here a screenshot of the terminal error]

Comment: @Laurenz: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932609/unable-to-edit-config-inc-php

Comment: @nohillside Ok i have installed it and finally modify config.inc.php. But i have another problem. When i try to connect with database from terminal out of the virtual machine and i use mysql -uroot, terminal give me that error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2). Have you ever seen anything like this?

Comment: I haven't even used LAMPP before :-) Maybe questions like that are better asked on https://community.apachefriends.org/

Comment: @nohillside Ok thank you soo much, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAMPP-VM runs within a Linux VM, so you can't access the config files directly within the macOS filesystem. To access the VM either open Terminal from the XMPP launcher

[image]

or run

```
ssh -i ~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.64.2
```

By default the XAMPP VM doesn't include any editor at all so you need to install one using `apt-get`:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nano
```

Afterwards you can run `nano /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` to edit the file.

PS: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932609/unable-to-edit-config-inc-php